# When is the targetsqltype parameter required is PreparedStatement.setObject

Tags: java, jdbc

The PreparedStatement has a

```
setObject(int parameterIndex,Object x,int targetSqlType)
```

method.  When would  one ever require the the third parameter?  Can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

I did find one circumstance where this is useful.  The sql server driver sends strings as unicode by default to the server.  So let's say you have a table:

```
create table1 (x varchar(128) primary key);
```

Now I form a sql:

```
String sql = select * from table1 where x = ?;
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatment(sql);
ps.setObject(1, "hello");
```

The string hello gets sent as unicode as if you issued a

```
select * from table1 where x = N'hello'
```

However that is not what is wanted because sql server will not use primary key index on x to search.  This happens if the MS JDBC driver has setSendStringParametersAsUnicode set to true.   If you set the setSendStringParametersAsUnicode to false the above will work but not for unicode. So there you need to do ps.setObject(1, "hello", Types.NVARCHAR).